# How to write Jsoup selector for fetching elements containing text in page that are not anchor tags?

Tags: java, jsoup

Suppose this is my HTML

```
//other html content

<div class="content">
    <p>This is a test page number 1</p>
    <a href="/test-page-2">Link to test page 2</a>
    <div>This gives more description about the test page</div>
</div>

<div class="content-2">
    <p>This is another test page content</p>
    <a href="/test-page-3">Link to test page 3</a>
</div>

//other html content
```

I need to write a selector using JSoup to find all the elements that have "test page" in them, excluding links to other pages.

So, far I've done this:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class~=content.*]:contains(test page)");
```

This will return the 2 p-elements, 2 anchor tag elements and the div element. I just want the 2 p-elements and the div element.

How do I write the selector for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS selector

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class^=content] > *:contains(test page)")
                                                                  .not ("a");
```

This will give `<p>` and `<div>` child elements content* css class parent elememnt.

```
<p>This is a test page number 1</p>
<div>
   This gives more description about the test page
</div>
<p>This is another test page content</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The element however could be anything like div, p, h1, span, etc. Anything except <a> but should contain the text. Is there anyway to negate the selector? Like `div[class~=content.*] > not a:contains(test page)`

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya Please check the updated answer. let me know if I missed any condition.